# Sufficient & necessary conditions for comparing sums of square roots: $\sum_{i=0}^m \sqrt{x_i} \ge \sum_{j=0}^n \sqrt{y_j}$

Tags: inequality, radicals

I'm trying to implement an algorithm for comparing sums of square roots, i.e. to find out whether one sum is greater than/equal to the other
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \sqrt{x_i} \ge \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \sqrt{y_j}
$$
where $m$ may be not equal to $n$.

The problem is that we can't in general calculate square root "exactly" and cumulative error (even with increased precision) causes problems downstream.

I have no problems for $m + n < 5$, because it can be solved using consecutive squaring, but it's not always the case.

So I want to know if there exists some sufficient condition which doesn't involve square roots or some iterative process that minimises them.

Knowing about [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) and the fact that square root is concave we can show that
$$
\sqrt{m \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} x_i} \ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \sqrt{x_i}
$$
also following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/444640/609857) we have
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \sqrt{x_i} \ge \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} x_i}
$$
hence something like
$$
m \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} x_i \ge \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} y_j
$$
is necessary condition for original inequality
and
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} x_i \ge n \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} y_j
$$
is sufficient one,
which is great because doesn't involve any square roots, but I hope this can be improved.

So I want to know if there are "more precise" ones. Ideally something like
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} x_i \ge \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} y_j
\implies
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \sqrt{x_i} \ge \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \sqrt{y_j}
$$
will be awesome.